# Logic. Does RHS imply LHS?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

Does RHS implies LHS here: $\exists x[P(x)\land\neg Q(x)] : \neg \forall x[P(x) \to Q(x) ]$

I know that LHS implies RHS and I could prove it. However, I think that RHS does not imply LHS, but I cannot think of counter example.

Comment: $\exists x[\lnot K(x)]$ is equivalent to $\lnot \forall x[K(x)]$.  And $P(x)\to Q(x)$ is equivalent to $\lnot(P(x)\lnot Q(x)$.

Comment: I understand this, but I need to write natural deduction proof and I cannot get to the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are equivalent, because $¬∀x \ [P(x) \to Q(x)] \equiv ∃x \ ¬[P(x) \to Q(x)]$, by [De Morgan's laws for quantifiers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws#Extension_to_predicate_and_modal_logic).

In turn, we have $\lnot (Px \to Qx) \equiv \lnot(\lnot Px \lor Qx)$ by [Material implication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_implication_(rule_of_inference)).

Then applying [propositional De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws#Negation_of_a_disjunction) we get :

> $\lnot (Px \to Qx) \equiv (Px \land \lnot Qx)$.

---

For a Natural Deduction derivation of the propositional equivalence :

1) $\lnot (Px → Qx)$ --- premise

2) $Qx$ --- assumed [a]

3) $Px \to Qx$ --- from 2) by $\to$-intro

4) $\bot$ --- from 1) and 3)

5) $\lnot Qx$ --- from 2) and 4) by $\to$-intro, discharging [a]

6) $\lnot Px$ --- assumed [b]

7) $Px$ --- assumed [c]

8) $Qx$ --- from 6) and 7)

9) $Px \to Qx$ --- from 7) and 8) by $\to$-intro, discharging [c]

10) $\bot$ --- from 1) and 9)

11) $\lnot \lnot Px$ --- from 6) amd 10) by $\to$-intro, discharging [b]

12) $Px$ --- from 11) by Double Neg

13) $Px \land \lnot Qx$ --- from 5) and 12) by $\land$-intro

> 14) $\lnot (Px \to Qx) \to (Px \land \lnot Qx)$ --- from 1) and 13).

---

15) $(Px \land \lnot Qx)$ --- premise

16) $Px$ --- from 15) by $\land$-elim

17) $\lnot Qx$ --- from 15) by $\land$-elim

18) $(Px \to Qx)$ --- assumed [a]

19) $Qx$ --- from 16) and 18) by $\to$-elim

20)$\bot$ --- from 17) and 19)

21) $\lnot (Px \to Qx)$ --- from 18) and 20) by $\to$-intro, discharging [a]

> 22) $(Px \land \lnot Qx) \to \lnot (Px \to Qx)$ --- from 15) and 21).

The equivalence follows from 14) and 22) by Bi-conditional introduction.

---

---

Now we can "embed" the derivation above into the quantificational part. For the RHS to LHS :

1) $\lnot \forall x \varphi$ --- premise

2) $\lnot \exists x \lnot \varphi$ --- assumed [a]

3) $\lnot \varphi$ --- assumed [b]

4) $\exists x \lnot \varphi$ --- from 3)

5) $\bot$ --- from 2) and 4)

6) $\varphi$ --- from 3) and 5) by *Double Negation*, discharging [b]

7) $\forall x \varphi$ --- from 6) by $\forall$-intro

8) $\bot$ --- from 1) and 7)

> 9) $\exists x \lnot \varphi$ --- from 2) and 8) by *Double Negation*, discharging [a].

Comment: Maybe you could give me hints how to prove it in predicate calculus?

Comment: @Augustas Hint: deMorgan's Laws and Implication Equivalence.

Comment: I got stuck 
1.¬∀x [P(x)→Q(x)] Premise {1}
2. ¬(P(a) -> Q(a) )  Hypothesis{2}
3. ¬(P(a) ^ Q(a))     Hypothesis{3}
4. ¬(¬P(a) v ¬Q(a)) Hypothesis{4}
5. ¬P(a)                   Hypothesis{5}
6. ¬ P(a) v Q(a)       v-intro
7. contradiction        ^-intro4,6
8.¬¬P(a)                   ¬-intro5,7
9. P(a)                       ¬¬-elim8
10. Q(a)                     Hypothesis{10}
11. Q(a) v ¬P(a)         v-intro
12. contradiction         ^-intro4,11
13. ¬Q(a)                   ¬-intro10,12
14. P(a) ^ ¬Q(a)          ^-intro13,9
15. contradiction         ^-intro14,3  
16. ¬Pa v Qa

Comment: @Augustas - but the issue is: what is the *proof system* you are using ?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA natural deduction

Answer (score 2):

$\neg \forall x [Px \to Qx] \equiv \exists x \neg [Px \to Qx] \equiv \exists x [Px \wedge \neg Qx]$